# Strange furry results with airbrush

Tags: painting, airbrush

I'm doing plastic models, started airbrushing recently, had a "toy" compressor, I was happy with it, but it broke, and I'm trying got [this new one](https://www.cmmodellismo.it/it/compressori/3996-fengda-mini-compressore-as-18-2.html).
But somehow I'm getting this result, a somewhat furry texture of the painting, not sticking to the surface, like some sticky stuff would put on before the painting. I'm using Revell enamel paint. Tried with one of my greens and this black, same results.
Is it a known problem?

[image]

After waiting to dry and lightly brushed with a clean brush:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The paint needs to be thin and uniform for air brushing.  That looks like clumps of paint.  A few conditions can cause that:

- The paint is too thick.
- The paint isn't uniformly thinned, so some of what the air brush sprays is "chunks" and sputters rather than mist.
- Too much solvent is evaporating on the way to the surface (choice of solvent, amount of solvent, and distance from the surface).
- The nozzle isn't staying clean.  Paint collects around the nozzle and then big droplets are projected at the surface by the spray.
- You're applying too heavy a layer.  Use many light layers rather than going for heavy coverage in one pass.